# selectionStyle not working with UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I want to have some of my cells not respond to user interaction and am trying to set via:

```
  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    ....
    if let header = tmpTableItem as? EKHeader {
      tableViewCell.textLabel!.text = menuHeader.name
       tableViewCell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone
    } ....
```

but am getting the error:

> Use of unresolved identifier  UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone

But this seems to be the correct way to inhibit user interaction in a `UITableViewCell`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

change this line

```
 tableViewCell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone
```

to

```
 tableViewCell.selectionStyle = .None  // In swift 3.0 and above use `.none`
```

Comment: should be .none

Comment: @jiawen yeah its in 3.0 where answer is about a year ago where swift 1.1 is there ..